# gets() inside switch being ignored

Tags: c

Can someone tell me why the gets in the `case 1` is being completely ignored?

```
    // #define M 50 is at the top

    char product[M] = {0};
    int choice = -1;

    printf("Command: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice){

        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:
            printf("Product: ");
            gets(product);
            insert_product(warehouse, price, product);
            break;

        case 2:
            // print_all();
            break;

        default:
            printf("Scelta non valida\n");
            break;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `gets`?  This API is extremely dangerous and is an exploit waiting to happen.

Comment: You are not providing any information about `choice`. What is it? How do you set its value?

Comment: @JaredPar Because someone demanded me and security is not a problem for now because i'm learing C. I know I should use fgets instead :)

Comment: @Tudor Added more informations :)

Comment: So you are reading 1 and the case for 1 is not executed?

Comment: @Tudor When choice equals 1 the case 1 is executed but the gets() is being completely ignored. Just like if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gets might be skipped by an ending char from a previous input. Try adding a getchar() before the gets to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the newline you input when reading `choice`:

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

is being taken as input for the next `gets(product);` and so it reads an empty string. Try to add an artificial `getchar` after `scanf` to absorb the newline:

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
getchar();
```

Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

First, the important bit...

**NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`.  Ever.  Even for practice code.  Even if someone else tells you to.  It's like the movie *Highlander II*; it's just best to pretend it never existed.  It was deprecated in C99 and has been completely removed from C2011.  Don't use it.  Don't try to justify using it by claiming this is just practice code.  If someone else demands you use it, push back and tell them you'll use `fgets` instead.  If they give you grief, send them to me and I'll straighten them out.  With a baseball bat if necessary.

Okay, now that I've cleared that up...

`gets` is picking up the trailing newline from the input you entered for the previous `scanf` call.  You have several choices:

1. Use another `scanf` call instead of `gets`, this time with the `%s` conversion specifier (along with a field width); unlike `gets`, it will skip over any leading newline characters;
2. Call `getchar()` (or equivalent) to consume the newline before calling `gets`;
3. Instead of reading `choice` as an integer using `scanf`, read it as text using `fgets` and convert it to an integer using `strtol`.

Option 3 is the best IMO.  Mixing calls to `scanf`/`fscanf` and `fgets` is usually a recipe for heartburn, precisely because of the trailing newline issue.  Better to stick with one or the other for *everything*.  The advantage of using `fgets` to read everything as text is that it makes input validation easier, especially for numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

// #define M 50 is at the top

```
char product[M] = {0};
int choice = -1;

printf("Command: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice){

    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        printf("Product: ");
        getchar();
        gets(product);
        insert_product(warehouse, price, product);
        break;

    case 2:
        // print_all();
        break;

    default:
        printf("Scelta non valida\n");
        break;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `fflush(stdin)` before using `gets` as input as the `gets` is taking newline character as input after the use of `scanf("%d", &choice);`

`fflush(stdin)` clears the output buffer and moves the buffered data to console.